# SharePoint 2010 :Search a document using its URL in Crawl Log in Central admin: Displays More than one successful result

Tags: document-library, search-scope

In a document library When we try to open some documents using their document ID link, then instead of opening the document several copies of that document are displayed.In an ideal situation only one result should have been there and the document should have opened automatically on clicking Document ID link.

On further investigation we found that for these documents more than one successful result is displayed when we search these documents in crawl log(in central admin) using its URL. In an ideal situation(if there had been no issue) there would have been only a single successful search result.

We have checked all the properties of the documents. We have not been able to conclude that why this anomaly is arising for some documents and not for some.

Answer (score 0):

Use crawl rule for this issue, define the crawl to exclude the content you dont want to display in search result.

Comment: Excluding the content in the search results will not solve the problem. The issue is that it will still crawl the item more than once and will  display copies of the document when we click on Document ID link.